# HTML/CSS: How to Prevent Single Word Orphans Near Floated Elements?

Tags: html, css, orphan

When I have enough screen width, text wraps nicely around a right floated image (see first example below).  But when the viewport narrows, I can find a single word the the left of the image, with the rest of the text below it, especially if one of the first few words is longer in length (see second example below).

Short of adding extra left margin on the image (which would look weird when there's plenty of space), is there anything I can do to prevent this?

I won't know ahead of time either the actual text content nor the width of the viewport.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A little hacky but wrapping the first couple words in an element like `<span>` with `display:inline-block` forces that entire set of words to move as one "entity" so to speak.

```
<span style="display:inline-block">First couple words</span> rest of content....
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" />
<span>First couple words</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur blandit aliquam mauris, ut tempor elit vehicula ut. Cras quis consequat magna, quis viverra risus. Vestibulum et mattis felis, sed interdum ipsum. Nulla accumsan a turpis vitae scelerisque. Nulla dapibus imperdiet quam a dignissim. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed egestas sem nunc, nec semper tortor hendrerit a. Sed non cursus metus. Nunc nisl purus, accumsan sed ligula quis, mollis euismod mi. Vivamus at egestas diam. Morbi sed mi in est eleifend tempus nec non mauris. Etiam at iaculis magna, iaculis interdum lorem. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus elementum nisi tellus, ut vestibulum massa laoreet fermentum.

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I may have found another solution that's more semantically correct and doesn't require any manipulation of the text itself...

Since the problem is occuring when a floated image leaves a little bit of room for text, but not quite enough for it to flow nicely, I force the image to leave NO room for ANY text.

I do this with a media query - for the site I'm working on, @media (max-width: 550px) is the sweet spot.  On a class I already have on my images, I just add "width:99%".

When the viewport is >550px, there's enough room for text to flow properly.  Below 550px, where I didn't have much room anyway, the image now takes up nearly the full width and pushes the text below it.

Anyone see a problem doing it this way?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue properly, you could use clear:left property to resolve the issue shown here: [w3School](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_layout_clear)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to abuse your DOM, as in Kevin Pei's solution, you can abuse your text instead. Make the first space in your text a non-breaking space, `&nbsp;`, and the browser won't insert a line break there:

```css
img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://placehold.it/500x50">
Lorem&nbsp;ipsumdolorsitamet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur blandit aliquam mauris, ut tempor elit vehicula ut. Cras quis consequat magna, quis viverra risus. Vestibulum et mattis felis, sed interdum ipsum. Nulla accumsan a turpis vitae scelerisque. Nulla dapibus imperdiet quam a dignissim. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed egestas sem nunc, nec semper tortor hendrerit a. Sed non cursus metus. Nunc nisl purus, accumsan sed ligula quis, mollis euismod mi. Vivamus at egestas diam. Morbi sed mi in est eleifend tempus nec non mauris. Etiam at iaculis magna, iaculis interdum lorem. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus elementum nisi tellus, ut vestibulum massa laoreet fermentum.
</div>
```

<sub>Feels good to use &nbsp; for something other than empty table cells.</sub>